# GitHub API with PHP's cURL not getting right status response

Tags: php, curl, github, github-api

I am using WordPress's HTTP API which has a wrapper for cURL (I'll assume it can do everything PHP's cURL does).

Trying to check the following headers `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` via the API should return:

```
Status: 304 Not Modified
```

Instead I am getting a `Status: 200 OK`

Testing curl from the command line works fine and return the right status, this works:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/wycks -H 'If-None-Match: "7efeb402e491989a4f37d8d82aae8946"'
```

Entering the same ETag in PHP `'If-None-Match' => '7efeb402e491989a4f37d8d82aae8946'` doesn't work.

Here is my PHP request to the API:

```
array
  'method' => string 'HEAD' (length=4)
  'timeout' => int 5
  'redirection' => int 0
  'httpversion' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  'user-agent' => string 'WordPress/3.5; http://dev.local/Foo15' (length=37)
  'blocking' => boolean true
  'headers' => 
    array
      'Accept-Encoding' => string 'deflate;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5' (length=29)
  'cookies' => 
    array
      empty
  'body' => null
  'compress' => boolean false
  'decompress' => boolean true
  'sslverify' => boolean false
  'stream' => boolean false
  'filename' => null
  'If-None-Match' => string '7efeb402e491989a4f37d8d82aae8946' (length=32)
  'Cache-Control' => string 'must-revalidate' (length=15)
  '_redirection' => int 0
  'ssl' => boolean true
  'local' => boolean false
boolean true
```

And the *wrong* response:

```
response' => 
    array
      'code' => int 200
      'message' => string 'OK' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about underlying reasons but from some poking you need to quote etag value inside string:

```
'If-None-Match' => '"7efeb402e491989a4f37d8d82aae8946"'
```